# How to display image of selected UICollectioNViewCell in UIView? (Swift 3)

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

I am new to iOS development, so please bear with me if this is obvious.

I have a UICollectionView on the bottom half of a view controller; it currently displays all photos in my photo library. There is a UIView on the top half of the same view controller.

Q: When I select a UICollectionViewCell (i.e. a photo), how do I display that photo in the UIView on the same view controller?

I imagine I'll have to use didSelectItemAt somehow to save the index path of the selected image in order to display that image in the UIView. (I've included what I have thus far for didSelectItemAt.) How do I refresh the content of the UIView as different photos are selected?

```
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let selectedVideo = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath)
    selectedVideo?.alpha = 0.5
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didDeselectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let deselectedVideo = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath)
    deselectedVideo?.alpha = 1.0
}
```

Comment: you want to display it modal or push to another view controller?

Comment: Neither. I would like the selected photo to appear on the same screen. (Think Instagram photo selection screen.)

Comment: is 3D touch that you want to implement?

Comment: A bit of confused. Your code is for video, but you talked about image. If you just want to refresh the corresponding image with the selected image in collection view, you just need to set the image again to the view. Add an `IBOutlet` link to the image view, then set `imageView.image = selectedImage`. That's all.

Comment: No, just a tap.

Comment: I apologize for the confusion. I eventually want to be able to do this with videos but am trying out the code with images first to get the hang of it.

Comment: For clarification: This is why I wanted to try to use a UIView instead of a UIImageView so that I can switch over to eventually using AVPlayer. 

Again, I am new to this, so please feel free to let me know if I am approaching this the wrong way.

Comment: it is fine that you are using UIView for image/video in order to switch between the 2. but i'm still confused what you want to achieve. you mentioned that it is neither pushing to another view controller, nor it is performing 3D touch feature. please elaborate.

Comment: You can use anything you want, UIView or UIImageView. When you select an item in collection view, you just need to call the function to reload the top view. The reload function for video, such as re-assign data source for the video player, play video from the beginning...

Comment: @jo3birdtalk When I select a image/video from the UICollectionView, I want it to be displayed in the UIView located on the same screen. The UIView takes up the top half of the screen, while the UICollectionView takes up the bottom half of the screen. As I select a different image/video in the UICollectonView, I want that change to be reflected in the UIView.

Comment: @t4nhpt Do I need to write my own reload function to reassign the data source?

Comment: check my answer if as i understand your problem. @Jess

Comment: yes @Jess you put manually imageview into your view

Answer (score 5, accepted):

put `ImageView` into your view then make `IBOutlet` of imageview . you get cell of collectionview , set image of `collectionviewcell` of `imageview` image into top `imageView`

You can try this

```
 func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
            let selectedCell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath) as! MyCollectionViewCell
           yourview.imageView.image = selectedCell.imageView.image
        }
```

Comment: Do I need to make an IBOutlet of the imageview for the collectionViewCell?

Comment: if you put your own imageview otherwise you use

 yourview.imageView.image = selectedCell.imageView.image @Jess

Comment: I see, so I don't have to necessarily manually overlay an imageView on the UICollectionViewCell in the storyboard?

Comment: When you say, "put ImageView into your view", do you mean manually drag an image view into my UIView?

Answer (score 2):

From my understanding on the comments you have described earlier, there are 2 ways you can implement.

1. Using UIViewController, drop a UIView and a UICollectionView.
2. Using UICollectionViewController, and create a UICollectionReusableView

I'm assuming that you are using the 1st method,

Drop an `@IBOutlet` for the above UIImageView and name it `myImageView` for example.

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let selectedImage = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath)
        myImageView.image = selectedImage.myImageView.image
}
```

Comment: Let me know if you are implementing it on the 2nd method instead. I will update accordingly.

Comment: Your assumption is correct! Quick question: Do I need to drop another UIImageView onto the UIView, or is it possible to have UIView directly display an image? Sorry about the confusion...

Comment: you can do it by code without dropping another UIImageView. Just have to addSubview. But since you are new, just do it on the storyboard.

Comment: If I want to be able to eventually switch out the UIImageView for an AVPlayer, would it be better to add in the UIImageView using addSubview?

Comment: If you working with storyboard, just drop 2 items in there, and set isHidden property for the one you don't want to see.

Comment: Ah, okay--that makes sense. Thank you!!

Comment: I'm getting an error that "Value of type 'UICollectionViewCell' has no member 'imageView'/'image'" (depending on which one I try). What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let selectedVideo = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath)
    view.imageView.image = selectedVideo
}
```